# Make a SQL Query to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

How do I get this SQL query to LINQ?

```
  SELECT Customer.name
  FROM Company INNER JOIN Customer ON Company.CompanyId = Customer.CompanyId
  where CompanyId = 2
```

Comment: I'll get right to it, my lord.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one:

```
var result = from c in Companies
             join cu in Customers
             on c.CompanyId equals cu.CompanyId
             where c.CompanyId==2
             select cu.Name
```

or

```
var result = db.Companies
               .Join(Customers.Where(x==>x.CompanyId==2), 
                     x=>x.CompanyId, 
                     y=>y.CompanyId, 
                     y=>y.Name);
```

where `Companies` and `Customers` refer to you companies and customers respectively.